# How to generate the LR(0) finite state machine for a grammar

Tags: automata, formal-grammars

Here is a context-free grammar with a single nonterminal symbol S and three terminal symbols +, *, and s:

S -> + S S | * S S| s

My purpose is to build the [LR state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#LR_Generator_Analysis) for this grammar.  My attempt:

```
[State 0]      ->     [State 1]       ->       [State 2]
S -> . + S S   (+)    S -> + . S S    (*)      S -> * . S S
S -> . * S S          S -> . * S S             S -> . + S S //leads to loop
S -> .s               S -> .s
```

When I get to state 2, I see that an infinite loop begins to form. I think I am missing/misunderstanding part of the algorithm to form the machine. Can you ignore a production if it already exists somewhere else?

Comment: I looked up the web: CFSM is the **Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster**, which does not seem to be a topic for this site, though I wonder whether LR parsing could fit the sect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop, an item like $S\to \bullet{+}SS$ in your example might occur in several item sets of the LR automaton.  Let us continue the construction of state 2:

```
[State 2]
S -> * . S S
S -> . + S S
S -> . * S S
S -> . s
```

It has transitions to itself on "$*$", to state 1 on "$+$", to some state 3 with item set $\{S\to s\bullet\}$ on "$s$", and to yet another state on "$S$":

```
[State 4]                 [State 5]
S -> * S . S   --(S)-->   S -> * S S .
S -> . + S S
S -> . * S S
S -> . s
```

State 4 has again a transition to state 1 on "$+$", state 2 on "$*$", and state 3 on "$s$".  The construction is not complete yet, since you are missing some outgoing transitions from states 1 and 0, but hopefully you can finish it yourself.